# In the US, what can be done at an airport when volunteering hours?

Tags: airport, usa

I am a 15 years old and need volunteering hours for my course work. I am a aviation enthusiast with knowledge of the industry and love for anything that flies. I decided to fulfill my hours at a local airport because I would be helping others doing what I love. I am from Florida, and I know this is the greatest place for all aviation related things.

The tasks I would like to perform at my local airport are fueling, taxiing aircraft in and out of a ramp, and help with other airport operations.

Is any of this possible?

If anybody can give me any idea on how to do this. I also like any advice to help me further my volunteering path with other aviation related tasks.

Comment: Which airport? Some commercial airports have volunteers that staff information desks, help direct passengers, even to bring around dogs for passengers to pet. It's not taxiing aircraft, but it would be a way to get a foot in the door. You'd need to contact the airport's management to see if they have such a program and whether you're eligible.

Answer (score 9):

Commercial airports are challenging for volunteers because of security, if you want to do anything beyond the security barrier (ie where the interesting stuff is) then you need to be cleared and supervised, and that costs time and money.

There may be opportunities at small airports, which don't have the same security concerns. Most won't have any established volunteer positions, it would be more of a case of talking to the airport manager or someone running an FBO and asking if there's anything you could volunteer for. Ask politely, wait a few days, then follow up with a phone call, if they know you're genuinely interested (and polite, sensible, not likely to run into a propeller) they might be willing to offer something to you.

One last thing, if anyone asks you to get a bucket of propwash it's an old aviation joke.

Answer (score 5):

Working as a volunteer at an airport may be problematic, because almost everything at most airports is (a) a for-profit enterprise, and (b) involves liability. Those factors make it more likely to use paid, trained, accountable employees instead of volunteer temporary help.

That said, there are aviation-related volunteer opportunities out there if you can expand your criteria a bit. Aviation museums tend to do lots more with volunteers, and that would be the first place I'd suggest looking for leads. You won't be fueling or taxiing aircraft, but working around docents with a career of aviation experience, you'll pick up a wealth of stories & advice.

Some large airports may have volunteer greeter positions (i.e. "Which way to baggage claim C please") available, but I'd start with museums for a closer connection to fliers & flying machines.

Best of luck in your search!

Answer (score 4):

[Civil air patrol](http://www.gocivilairpatrol.com/).  They fly GA aircraft in service to the nation.  Technically an auxiliary of the Air Force, they do search and rescue, disaster relief, aerospace education, a cadet program, homeland security, assisting law enforcement, all sorts of things.  And yes, they have a youth program.

Aviation museums.

And one that many people overlook, *naval* aviation museums.   Like the USS Intrepid, Midway, Hornet etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would go to your local airport and contact the manager. Many airports have a public space, and most of the ones I've been to could definitely use some attention.  You could see if there are touch up jobs you could do there. I'm wondering if railings need new paint or new signs could be placed. Paint parking stalls. Replace tie downs. Others have mentioned liabilities working around aircraft. I don't image you could do much that involves being near or interacting with planes without waivers and training...

Also, lots of airports like to host events. I've been to many of these and there is often a lot going on. I'm sure there is a way to volunteer there, even if its just taking tickets at the gate or guiding visitors.

Good Luck